# Why is my datetime model property required

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have a vb.net MVC3 project (.net 3.5) and inside this project is a model with a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`).

This property has no `<required()>` annotation, yet for some reason its not allowed to be left empty in the form. When it is, it generates a validation error of "A value is required."

Comment: It's likely that you are not using a nullable DateTime as the property, so MVC needs a value provided.

Comment: That's not the case, I'll update my questions to reflect this.

Comment: Are other non-required fields passing validation when empty? Could you be using an additional client-side validation script/plug-in?

Comment: check **modelstate** and find out which form property does produce this error ? it look like you have another property with required which is validated

Comment: Unobtrusive validation does not generate _"A value is required"_ (it would be _"The ### field is required"_ (where ### is the name of your property) so its the result of something else.

Answer (score 0):

So, the nullable thing is important. Once nullable, the datetime can get bound to nothing after the containing object, the model, is autobound as a controller parameter. If you have this same issue, be sure to set your datetime to a new datetime, or else the views will flip out about having nothing for the editorFor helpers.

Its also important, apparently, to shut down visual studio every so often. The connection between IIS Express and visual studio seems to get flaky from time to time: It looks like an older version of my site kept getting deployed instead of the version I had in front of me.